# No Solution explorer now showing Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

Here, the folder contains two files through which I can access the code of the project in visual studio: **Program.cs & ProgrammingAssignment3.csproj**

[image]

When I open the **Program.cs** file there is no *Solution Explorer*, which helps in accessing different custom classes.

[image]

Even if I tried adding it from the *View window*:[image]
It doesn't show anything inside it.[image]

I also tried *Tools < Options < Projects and Solutions* but there's no changes.
[image]

But here when I open this **.csproj file**:[image]
The *solution explorer* is shown and *also the classes*.[image]
But unfortunately, as I **need program.cs** file for my work, I **can't use the .csproj file**. And this not just for this project but every other too. Please tell me how should I get appear the *Solution explorer* *in the program.cs* file so that I can write code easily by accessing the classes. I don't mean I've problem with the .csproj file, I want the solution explorer to get running in program.cs file.

Comment: _"But unfortunately, as I need program.cs file for my work, I can't use the .csproj file."_ - this is highly irregular. Without a .csproj, you don't have a project, you just have a code file. A code file needs to belong to a project, otherwise how can you compile it? How does it what compiler settings to use?

Comment: @Llama You're right, I don't have a problem with .csproj file. I am saying my work need solution explorer in program.cs file which is not happening yet with me.

Comment: Open your Unity project in Unity first, then double-click a script in the **Project** window.  Unity will create any .csproj files as necessary as well as your .sln file and launch Visual Studio.  Without the latter VS's **Solution** window won't show.  Remember, Unity .csproj <> regular C# .csproj files.

Comment: You know Solution Explorer displays the contents of a solution (a .sln file), right? A solution contains projects, and a project contains code files, etc. So if you want a `.cs` file to show in Solution Explorer, you really need a solution (.sln), which contains a project (.csproj), which contains your .cs files.

Comment: @MickyD Even when i open a script(after creating it) from the Unity, I get the same interface as the 2nd pic(of the posted question), just the different code.

Comment: Going by the photos I can see you have in fact opened a solution called **Solution1** but _it has no projects added to it_.  To fix, either **a)** see if there is a **.sln** file in the `parent` folder **d:\C & Uni\ProgrammingAssignment3**. If so, open that otherwise **b)** in the **Solution Explorer** view, right-click **Solution 'Solution1' (0 projects)** click **Add > Existing project...** and browse to your .csproj files.  Repeat as necessary

Comment: BTW, the code shown above is **not** Unity code.  Why tagged Unity?

Comment: @MickyD When I create a C# script from the unity in a folder, for instance EXE1 as the name of the script, and after browsing to the folder where the script is located, there are only two files which are there: 1)EXE1.cs & 2) EXE1.cs.meta . No solution file or .csproj file, so that's where I am facing the problem most as if I'd working just in visual studio I could add easily in the soultion explorer through the existing project buttons and so forth. But while working with Unity i can't happen to see where can I browse through the .csproj file of existing project.

Comment: _"...No solution file or .csproj file..."_ - Unity-created **.csproj** and **.sln** files are created in your _Unity project folder_. It is your projects _root folder_.  It contains child folders **Assets**, **Packages**, **ProjectSettings** and so forth.  Your Unity _assets_ (textures, models, prefabs, shaders and **scripts**) are naturally stored in the **Assets** folder or a child folder thereof, that's why you can't find them.

Comment: _"When I create a C# script from the unity in a folder, for instance EXE1 as the name of the script, and after browsing to the folder where the script is located, there are only two files which are there: 1)EXE1.cs & 2) EXE1.cs.meta . No solution file or .csproj file"_ - again, the code and screenshots shown above in your question **have nothing to do with Unity**

Comment: Create a C# script: Assets→Create→C#Script After creating a blank script, change the name of the script. Note that the script name is important. For example, name the script: test.cs, and a C# file is created.

Answer (score 0):

The class (**.cs**) is in your project (**.csproj**), and the project is **always** in a solution (**.sln**). The solution **isn't** accessible when its part of your *Unity* project.

If you open the project file directly from the file explorer you can edit the class **program.cs** from there.

You could also open the script from Unity itself and it brings you there too.

Answer (score 0):

1. check if you multiple installation for VS
2. go to environment varaible and remove if you have duplicate entiries of old one
3. follow below steps:
   tool Menu-->Import Export Setting--> Reset All setting --> Next ---> No Just reset my setting --> Next--> general development setting --> finish

it should fix the issue