# Can't access classes of Unity

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

Here, when I open the highlighted script in a Unity Project:
[image]
The visual studio opens and there's *no solution explorer*:
[image]
and even if I add it from *View* tab, there's nothing in it to be accessed or browsed.[image]

Due to this I'm not able to access Unity classes like in this example *Vector3* class cannot be accessed which can be noticed as it's not color coded.[image]
How can this problem be solved?

Comment: How does _this_ question differ to the one you posted 2 hours earlier?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71217371/no-solution-explorer-now-showing-visual-studio.  At least now you  are showing Unity code and aren’t showing code for a console app

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No Solution explorer now showing Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71217371/no-solution-explorer-now-showing-visual-studio)

Comment: Delete the script that cannot be hung up, add the script again, and restart the editor of Unity

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sometimes your visual studio is out of sync with your Unity. Some methods I used to fix this are:

- Greate a new script and delete it
- Editor->prefences-> and set your coding application to visual studio 2019 or any other version

Answer (score 0):

you need to update your visual studio to latest update.
if this didn't work out you'll have to change to vs 2022